# Crossword digitization using image processing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am a newbie to image processing.I need to convert a crossword grid in an image file into into corresponding binary equivalent i.e Output should be an array with 1 for the black squares and a 0 for the white squares. 
Also all other extraneous information in the image like text etc to be ignored and digitize only the grid.

Can the corner detection algorithm help us detect the corners of the crossword and then digitize blocks of pixels accordingly using brute force?, Is this the best way to do it or are there any efficient methods  to accomplish the task? I would prefer python based solution.

[image: crossword sample]

Comment: not interested in a matlab solution at all?

Comment: no its not homework :). Matlab solution is OK too @GaryTsui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need not use corner detection here. Just using contours itself, you can solve it (if your images are these straight forward). Below is an code which prints the array for your above image. Codes are commented :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('cross.jpg')    
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
thresh2 = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 1)

max_area = -1

# find contours with maximum area
for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True), True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > max_area:
            max_area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            max_cnt = cnt
            max_approx = approx

# cut the crossword region, and resize it to a standard size of 130x130
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(max_cnt)
cross_rect = thresh2[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cross_rect = cv2.resize(cross_rect,(130,130))

# you need to uncomment these lines if your image is rotated
#new_pts = np.float32([[0,0], [0,129],[129,129],[129,0]])
#old_pts = max_approx.reshape(4,2).astype('float32')
#M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(old_pts,new_pts)
#cross_rect = cv2.warpPerspective(thresh2,M,(130,130))

cross = np.zeros((13,13))

# select each box, if number of white pixels is more than 50, it is white box
for i in xrange(13):
    for j in xrange(13):
        box = cross_rect[i*10:(i+1)*10, j*10:(j+1)*10]
        if cv2.countNonZero(box) > 50:
            cross.itemset((i,j),1)

print cross
```

I got an output like this for your above image :

```
[[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]]
```

I have written a code to extract sudoku details from an image with detailed explanation at below links (Tutorial is incomplete). You can refer them for more details:

http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/sudoku-solver-part-1.html

http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/sudoku-solver-part-2.html

http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/some-common-questions.html

Comment: Thanks,Thats a great solution, can you explain why you considered 130*130? does each block have 10 pixels? and also elaborate box = cross_rect[i*10:(i+1)*10, j*10:(j+1)*10]

Comment: Since it is a 13x13 block, I took a multiple of 13. that's all. Second one is taking each 10x10 block, from left-to-right, top-to-bottom and analyze it. Put some values of i and check how eqn comes.

Comment: thanks , perhaps I need to wait for a few other answers before accepting this one. There can be multiple solutions with completely different approaches.

Comment: sure... also think for own ideas... :)

Answer (score 1):

Corner detection may find corners on text etc - you will have to try that.

I would start by finding lines using the Hough transform http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html.
Once you detect all the straight lines you can find the corners of the squares by finding the intersections of the lines. Once you know where the squares are it would be simple to determine whether the square is black or white.

You can also write a Hough transform to detect rectangle, but that is probably unnecessary complication.

Whether you do it in Python, C++, Java makes not much difference.